# Personalizar calendario C#

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar

No sistema que estou fazendo, preciso de um calendário que tenha somente os finais de semana de cada mês habilitados para serem selecionados, o restante fica apagado..

Como posso fazer isso em C# Winforms?

Pesquisei na internet e aqui no Forum e não achei nada exatamente assim, achei algumas coisas mas não consegui fazer o que eu quero.

Comment: não entendi bem, seria tipo:

dom seg ter qua qui sex sab

 1                       7
 8                       14
15                       21
22                       28
29

esse seria um exemplo correto?

Comment: a formatação não pega aqui, imagine q no mês que falei dia 1 é domingo e ele só mostra sabado e domingo no calendário.

Comment: Isso. Por exemplo, no mes de Janeiro de 2015 só vai habilitar para selecionar os finais de semana (sábado e domingo) assim como os demais meses. Só habilita finais de semana.

Comment: é pra ser exibido em que forma? lista? tabela?

Comment: No calendario mesmo do Windows Form o MonthCalendar. Só que dai ficaria habilitado para selecionar somente os sábados e domingos de cada mês.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilizando o `MonthCalendar` nativo, o máximo que você poderá fazer é verificar se a data selecionada é um sábado ou um domingo, algo assim:

```
private void monthCalendar_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    // se a data selecionada for diferente de domingo e sábado
    if (e.Start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        // seleciona o primeiro domingo anterior a data selecionada
        monthCalendar.SelectionStart = monthCalendar.SelectionStart
            .AddDays(-(Double)e.Start.DayOfWeek);
        monthCalendar.SelectionEnd = monthCalendar.SelectionStart;

        // exibe mensagem de data fora do intervalo
        MessageBox.Show("Você não pode selecionar nenhuma data entre segunda e sexta.", 
            "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Se realmente isso não te atende, você pode tentar utilizar um dos controles personalizados abaixo:

- [MonthCalendar 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24450/MonthCalendar-Calendar-Control)
- [MonthCalendar 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar)

No `MonthCalendar 1`, você tem o evento `MonthDayRender`, onde você pode impedir que os dias da semana sejam criados.

```
private void monthCalendar1_MonthDayRender(object sender, MonthCalendar.MonthDayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.WeekDay != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.WeekDay != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        e.OwnerDraw = true;
    }
}
```

Algo que talvez também seja interessante para você nesse controle é a propriedade `ShowTrailingsDays` que fica dentro da propriedade `MonthDays`, essa propriedade oculta os dias anteriores e posteriores ao mês atual do calendário.

No `MonthCalendar 2`, você tem o evento `DayRender`, que também pode impedir que os dias da semana sejam criados.

```
private void monthCalendar2_DayRender(object sender, Pabo.Calendar.DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        e.OwnerDraw = true;
    }
}
```

Aparentemente o `MonthCalendar 1` é mais completo e possibilita uma personalização maior.

> **Observação:** nunca cheguei a utilizar nenhum dos dois componentes, os encontrei após realizar algumas pequisas pela internet.